# How to send the TAB button using Python In SendKey and PywinAuto Modules

Tags: python, pywinauto

This is the my code which will open the window and send the keys to the window but some screen s are not working

```
from pywinauto.application import *
import time
app=Application.Start("Application.exe")
app.window_(title="Application")
time.sleep(1)
app.top_window_().TypeKeys("{TAB 2}")
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Be sure you are using exactly needed window. 
   `top_window_()` may return quite another window.

To check, run:

```
app.top_window_().DrawOutline() #Highlight the window
```

2.The window can be not active, set it focus before the typing:

```
window = app.top_window_()
window.SetFocus()
window.TypeKeys("{TAB 2}")
```

3.More, you may need to click on the window.

```
window.Click()
window.TypeKeys("{TAB 2}")
```